# Click on a day to create an event

Tags: views, datetime

I'm wondering whether it is possible to simply click on a Drupal calendar tile (month view) and be automatically taken to the page for creating an event. The only thing I've found that comes close to this is the event [calendar module](https://drupal.org/project/event_calendar), specifically the *In-place Add/Edit/View of events in pop-up* functionality. However I need more control over this and want it to use my own content type for creation.

My colleague, who creates many calendar events, wanted this functionality to save time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom module you can implement [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7). It will allow you to change the views title before rendering.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view_name') {
    $title  = drupal_get_title();
    drupal_set_title(l($title,"node/add/event"));
  }
}
```

Not exactly but close to what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is helpful. Excuse my ignorance, but where is it best to add this function? I'm using views and calendar modules.

Comment: @user2540566 You put this code in your custom module file like `yourmodule.module`. However, what this code does is only to change the views title to a link to add a new content.

Answer (score 0):

The [Calendar](https://drupal.org/project/calendar) module has this functionality out-of-box.

1. Edit your calendar view
2. Under 'Format' Section, click 'Settings' for 'Show: Calendar Entities'
3. Scroll down and find 'Add new date link' and select your content type.

[image: Screenshot for step 2]
[image: Screenshot for step 3]

Comment: Thank you for your response, Елин Й. That's exactly the functionality I'm after, however I'd like to put this function on he actual 'day' tile on the month calendar.